# What is the option to sort records before inter-row calculation?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, subquery, sql-order-by

I have a time sequence data set to analyze but the difficulty is that

1. the data set is very big.
2. the time sequence events are committed by different objects with affiliation.
3. its in mysql, there is no id like index column to join

e.g.

```
----------------
dt     obj        comp
----------------
t1,    object_a,   component_1
t2,    object_b,   component_1
t3,    object_c,   component_3
t4,    object_a,   component_1
t5,    object_c,   component_2
t6,    object_b,   component_3
----------------
```

I am trying to know the delay between each commit 
from each component of each object.
i.e.
obj_a.comp_1.delay1 = obj_a.compoent_1.t4 - obj_a.component_1.t1

etc.

I tried to join

```
select timediff( t1.dt, t.dt ) as delay
from  table as t 
join table as t1
on t1.dt = (
    select min(t2.dt)
    from table as t2
    where t2.obj = t.obj 
    and t2.comp = t.comp 
    and t2.dt > t.dt
)
```

but it is taking forever, so I am thinking if there is any way to sort on the results and do inter-row calculation with variables, it would be much faster.
but it failed every way with sub-query and views where the sort is always done after calculation. From what I read on `order by`, it seems impossible. So what options do I have to to achieve this reasonably fast?

Answer (score 0):

We will stick with your structure.  You are missing a `join` condition:

```
select timediff( t1.dt, t.dt ) as delay
from table t join
     table t1
     on t1.obj = t.obj and t1.comp = t.comp and
         t1.dt = (select min(t2.dt)
                  from table t2
                  where t2.obj = t.obj and 
                        t2.comp = t.comp and
                        t2.dt > t.dt
                 );
```

Then, with this structure you want indexes on `table(obj, comp, dt)`.

Now, that is with your structure.  A simpler method would just use a subquery:

```
select timediff((select min(t2.dt)
                  from table t2
                  where t2.obj = t.obj and 
                        t2.comp = t.comp and
                        t2.dt > t.dt
                 ),
                 t.dt
                ) as delay
from table t;
```

You would want the same index.

The `join` method is needed if you need other columns from the matching row, other than `dt`.

Comment: Oops, thanks for fixing that. The latter version runs slightly faster than the join version. but that still have a lot of time penalty. The first one take 22 minutes and the latter one take 16 minutes.

Comment: (the above time also includes sorting records based on the obj and comp keys.) But if I sort the records first and put into a temporary table to preserve the order and do a inter-row subtraction, it takes only 5 minutes. The results are identical. (except for the few nective results in sorting). I still wonders if I can avoid the temporary table idea without much time penalty.

Comment: @Ben . . . Did you create the index?

Comment: nope, the actual data takes quite a few small views chained together to identify the component based on set of rules. and... its MySQL.